# Having an issue with phonegap facebook login without plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a phonegap app in iOS and I'm trying to do a login with facebook. I'm using the javascript sdk. When I try to use fb.getlogin status or fb.login, not sure which, it gives me this error:

*"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."*

I have searched for this error, obviously, but nothing seems to solve my issue.

I looked in the facebook app settings, and everything seems to be in order.

I'm probably crazy for asking this with so little detail, but, any suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used their SDK but I would have to guess that you are making the javascript calls from within your app and the SDK is saying that it doesnt recognize the URL that the call is coming from. Even though your phone doesn't have a URL (though you could give it one but that is a whole different story) it does still have an IP and that IP isnt matching what FB is expecting. I am sure you registered for a FB developer account or something like that and it asked for a URL of where the calls would be coming from. That needs to match. I dont know how you would get around this. I think you need to use the plugin.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I can't get around this by myself. But when I use a plugin, what does the plugin do different, I wonder, won't it have the same issues?

Comment: The plugin interfaces directly with the Facebook Android/iOS SDK. It does not use the javascript SDK even though you are using javascript to interface with the plugin. Dang... I felt weird just saying that. Also, the registration process is a bit different for the plugin.

Comment: I quit following the solution without the plugin, I just can't figure out the problem/solution.